# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined on registration page

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm trying to create a registration page for a website but I keep getting an Invalid parameter number error and I can't figure out why. Because I'm also getting a notice about passwords being an undefined index I'm certain this is causing the error but, I cannot see anything that would cause an issue.

```
 include('config.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Get username and password from the form as variables
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $passwords = $_POST['passwords'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];

    // Query records that have usernames and passwords that match those in the customers table

    $sql = file_get_contents('sql/insertUsers.sql');
    $params = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname,
        'passwords' => $passwords,
        'email' => $email,
        'birthdate' => $birthdate,
    );
    $statement = $database->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute($params);
    $users = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($users)) {
        // Set $user equal to the first result of $users
        $user = $users[0];

        // Set a session variable with a key of customerID equal to the customerID returned
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['userid'];

        // Redirect to the index.php file
        header('location: index.php');
    }
}
```

this is the mysql table that will contain the fields:

```
CREATE TABLE users_final (
    userid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    firstname CHAR(50),
    lastname CHAR(50),
    passwords VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,
    birthdate DATE
);
```

and this is my insert statement/file:

```
INSERT INTO users_final (username, firstname, lastname, passwords, email brithdate)
VALUES(:username, :firstname, :lastname, :passwords, :email, :brithdate)
```

I'm sure it's probably something small or stupid like a semicolon out of place but I am literally tearing my hair out trying to figure out why it thinks passwords is an undefined index. Here are the errors/notices in full
Notice: Undefined index: passwords on line 9

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined on line 25

Any help anyone can give me would be very appreciated.

Comment: `birthdate` != `brithdate`. Your query's parameter is misspelled as `brithdate`.

Comment: and there's a missing comma

Comment: You missed a comma in email brithdate in the query.. Plus the spelling mistake

Comment: and thiis `passwords VARCHAR(50)` also tells me that whatever you plan on using, is already unsafe. If you plan on using `password_hash()`, then it's too short.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. You have a comment about _// Query records that have ..._ but you open a file named `insertUsers.sql`. You also have a comment _// Set $user equal to the first result of $users_, but isn't this an INSERT query?

Comment: I knew it was something small like that thank you so much! The query was from a previous bit of code I'd had there and I have yet to remove it.